# Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in fluidpages\Classes\Provider\PageProvider.php line 193 after Typo3 upgrade

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I recently upgraded a typo3 project from 7.6.24 to 8.7.20 .
When I click any page in the back-end trying to view or edit any content element it throws this error:

"`PHP Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in typo3conf\ext\fluidpages\Classes\Provider\PageProvider.php line 193`"

Debuged code in that function `getControllerActionFromRecord()`, and a string offset didn't seem to be the case.

Any useful leads would be appreciated

my system info:

Typo3 : 8.7.20,

Php : 7.2,

fluidpages : 4.3.0

flux: 9.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Just try to remove the {0} from your controlerActionName variable in that function getControllerActionFromRecord() ...

Explanation:

When you do this

```
$parts = explode('->', $action);
$controllerActionName = end($parts);
```

You will most likely get back a string from end($parts).
See here documentation on "end()": https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

Im my experience, most of these "offset" errors in php 7.2 would have been "illegal typecast" errors in C++ e.g. ... I also get confused sometimes by them ...